# Visual Studio Find-Replace tool using Regex Capturing

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace, find

I am wondering if I can use a regex expression in Visual Studio's Find and Replace tool (Edit -> Quick Replace), to find:

`System.Nullable(Of X)`

and replace with:

`X?`

Where X is any object type such as Date, Guid, etc...
(The code is written in visual basic)

Example 1: 
The regex should be able to find: `System.Nullable(Of Guid)`, and replace this with: `Guid?`

Example 2: 
The **same** regex should be able to find: `System.Nullable(Of Integer)`, and replace this with: `Integer?`

So that I can use a find-replace regex expression to change:

`Public Property Id() As System.Nullable(Of Guid)`

to:

`Public Property Id() As Guid?`

to stop Visual Studio spamming me with "Name can be simplified"

Comment: Are you asking for a regex which can detect the type of `X`?  Answer: not easily.  Maybe you should give more examples so that your question is clear (not my downvote).

Comment: No. I am asking if it is possible to search for the pattern from the example given, and replace the found pattern with the text supplied using the find and replace tool. X doesn't really matter but it will always be a string of characters containing no whitespace characters (example: Date, Guid, Integer, ObjectName, etc...).

Comment: Again, please show several examples of what you have in mind.  The downvotes were given for a reason.

Comment: I've added an example. It seemed like a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `System\.Nullable\(Of (\w+)\)` and replace with `$1?`

Comment: You could also search for specific types e.g. `(Guid|Date)` instead of using `\w+`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's true, but since OP wants to get rid of the warning, I bet (s)he wants to replace every primitive types

Comment: @ThomasAyoub yes, exactly. I appreciate Tim pointing this out but it's unnecessary for my purpose.